# bitbucket authentication. wincred doesn't seem to work

Tags: windows, git, authentication, bitbucket, credentials

I faced a problem when I was building up my bitbucket repository.
I have done commit and push my files to remote repository.
But every time I try to push to my repository, it asks password.
Even though I set my gitconfig like below.

```
[user]
    email = my_email
    name = my_name
[credential]
    helper = wincred
```

And I also add 2 credentials to generic credentials in windows credential manager.

```
https://bitbucket.org        my_email_id / my_password
https://my_id@bitbucket.org  my_email_id / my_passowrd
```

I guess it should work. but it does not.
I searched a lot, but failed to find any solution for this problem.

waiting your help. thanks you.

Comment: You shouldn't need to manually add anything to Windows Credential Manager - wincred should do that for you. A good way to debug this sort of thing is to set `GIT_TRACE=1` on your command line - once that's set run your `git push` and you can see which credential helper git calls internally

Comment: Also, git is a bit weird in how it finds the config files, esp on Windows - try running `git config --global credential.helper wincred` instead of manually editing the file yourself

Comment: @rbennett485
thanks for answering :)
I solved this by adding git:https://id@bitbucket.org to windows credential and setting helper = wincred at gitconfig.